# cellphone heat generation

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature

- Cellphones = 1 billion phones (1,000,000,000)
- Environment = 1 billion KiloLiters water (1,000,000,000,000 Liters)
- Power = microwave radiation @ 1 watt/phone antenna
- Time period = 1 year / 365 days / 31,536,000 seconds

Question : How much can a Billion phones continuously radiating 1 watt @ 5 GHz each, heat a Billion Kiloliters of water, in one year ?

Comment: I shall consider that we live submerged in the ocean?

Comment: ^A very simplified scenario^

Comment: Ok i did it; with your data, heating of 7 Degrees celsius (all radiation absorbed)! However, the volume of the oceans is $10^{21}$ liters, more than your example, wich will give $7 * 10^{-5}$ deg

Comment: A lot of global warming just to download videos

Comment: 1 Cubic kilometer > $10^9$cubic meters,> $10^3 $liters. The formula is just (# phones*watts *time) /(mass of water * heat capacity)

Comment: what units do I use for time and heat capacity ?

Comment: Joule/ (Degrees* Kg)